# How can I pass a List<Interface> over WCF?

Tags: wcf, interface

I have a WCF service where I am trying to return a List (where IWatchable is a custom interface I have built) in one of my operation contracts. When I test the service on the client the method returns an **`object[]`** instead of **`List<IWatchable>`**. Is it possible to return a List of IWatchable, since IWatchable is an interface with WCF?

Method:

```
public List<IWatchable> GetWorkload( Guid nodeId, int maximum )
```

IWatchable:

```
public interface IWatchable
{
    string ActionName { get; set; }
    Guid ActionReference { get; set; }
}
```

Hopefully a bit more info will be helpful...

I have a derived interface:

```
public interface IAMRAWatchable: IWatchable
```

And three concrete implementations from `IAMRAWatchable`:

```
public class InstrumentationWatch: IAMRAWatchable
public class OutputWatch: IAMRAWatchable
etc...
```

In my WCF method that returns **`List<IWatchable>`** I want to send an `InstrumentationWatch` and an `OutputWatch` to the client... Is this possible or am I going about this the wrong way?

---

**Resolved**

Thanks to John I found my solution. **`KnownType`** wasn't working since I was using **`List<IWatchable>`** - So I wrapped my list into a new class and added the attributes to it. I'll need to re-factor my code but for others who are interested here is the class:

```
[DataContract]
[KnownType( typeof( InstrumentationWatch ) )]
[KnownType( typeof( OutputWatch ) )]
public class WorkInfo
{
    [DataMember]
    public List<IWatchable> WorkQueue { get; set; }
}
```

and my WCF method:

```
public WorkInfo GetWorkload( Guid nodeId, int maximum )
```

Comment: How did you create your client (from scratch/svcutil/Add Service Reference)?

Comment: I tried both with the same result

Comment: How about showing us how you implemented the KnownTypes attribute?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

An interface can never be serialized. It is only a description of behavior.

You can serialize objects which implement the interface, but you must tell WCF what their types are. See [Data Contract Known Types](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms730167.aspx).

Comment: I tried the KnownType attributes but I still couldn't get around my issue. Perhaps the extra information I provided will help clear up my exact issue. Thanks