# WCF Serialization & Interfaces

Tags: c#, vb.net, wcf, serialization

Does [link text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1220733/how-can-i-pass-a-listinterface-over-wcf) mean I have to return a concrete implementation?
Even though I am using svcutil with the /r that includes my entites(where IMyInterface is defined). I get no errors but it changes all List(of IMyInterface) to list(of Object) and I cannot deserialize it on the client

Error: list(of object) cannot be converted to list(of IMyInterface).

Regards

_Eric

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In short, yes. You must return a type that implements that interface. There's nothing to be serialized when passing an interface, there's no object to break down and pass over the wire, just list of properties and methods that need implemented.

Comment: Yikes! That's what I thought. Thanks