# Interface type as property of class throws error on client WCF

Tags: wcf

Hi I have a class which has a property of type of an interface

```
public class A
{
  public List<IInterface> interface {get;set;}
}

Public class B : IInterface
{
  // Some properties 
}
```

A wcf service is calling a `OpertaionContract` which return an object type of this object but it fails on my client.

I had already added the `ServiceKnowType` attribute on all implemented classes on the service contract but still i am getting the same error 
"Consider using a `DataContractResolver` or add the type corresponding to 'B' to the list of known types - for example, by using the `KnownTypeAttribute` attribute or by adding it to the list of known types passed to `DataContractSerializer`

I am really confused how this would work , please advise thanks.

I added the KnowTypeAttribute at the right datacontract so the above error went away but now I am getting a generic error of underline connection got closed.

**Updated:This link helped me out in resolving the Interface issue [How can I pass a List<Interface> over WCF?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1220733/how-can-i-pass-a-listinterface-over-wcf)
But right now enums are giving me a similar issue my object breaks on client cause of enums properties being defined in the class.**

Comment: Can you post your code where and how you defined `ServiceKnownTypeAttrubute`?

Comment: [ServiceContract] [ServiceKnownType(typeof(B))]  public interface IIService {//some function}

Answer (score 0):

for your enum problem, are you using EnumMember for the enums? See http://www.codekeep.net/snippets/0002f271-1418-4027-b19a-3820702fc22f.aspx for an example.

If that doesn't solve it, can you share the error message you're getting with the enum usage?